# Getting similar results from different classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I have a dataset with about3500 record and I want to do classification models on it.I use different models and preprocessing things but the results for different models are close to each other and doesn’t change that much.
I don’t know where is the problem, and I can’t change the data I’m using. What should I do to get better results?

I tried different models(simple,ensemble), different hyper parameter tuning methods, differing scaling methods,different outlier detection methods and whatever I knew I could do, but with all of these the results stays about the same (about: accuracy =0.77, f1 score =0.75, AUROC=0.84,..)
I also tried different feature selection methods and with different number of features but the result didn’t change that much.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, 3500 records is not very much data. Given that, I think your results (accuracy =0.77, f1 score =0.75) are actually pretty reasonable (not knowing anything else about the problem). It's very common to deploy models with this type of performance depending on the application.
With 3500 records, most nonlinear methods won't perform well, so model-wise there isn't much to be done. However, here is what I would suggest trying:

- try encoding your columns in different ways
- think about your problem space and see if there's any feature generation you can do based off your current features. This can remove some of the heavy-lifting from the model fitting process
- spend time investigating your data distribution (do some clustering, plotting, investigation)
- also investigate the distribution of classes/features in your FPs, TPs, FNs, and FPs. Sometimes an informative pattern will emerge

Finally, you can often find blog articles where people are solving similar problems. These can be a wealth of anecdotal advice and unintuitive tips/tricks.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A 0.77 accuracy is pretty much a good accuracy given the size of your data (3,500 records). When dealing with non-linear models, such data is insufficient for high model performance. I would suggest the following:

1. Use a pre-trained model (if one exists). Fine-tune the model and then test it with your records.
2. Try changing your splitting ratio. It's possible that 3,500 records with a ratio of 80:20 and 90:10 will have similar features appearing in both the train and test datasets.
3. Please note that Ensemble is a "bucket of models". It's possible that while trying out other models to see their accuracies, they could be part of those used with Ensemble. Try using a different alternative.
4. Do more data exploration and visualization to further understand your data and find definitive patterns that you wish to see in your model.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on data preparation. Feature engineering, feature selection. You can try various methods like PCA, ICA, Polynomial features, Feature Agglomeration, Autoencoder latent representations and most importantly using your domain knowledge of the subject to choose appropriate features to engineer.

For feature selection, you can use simple algorithms like SelectKBest or more advanced methods such as Recursive Feature Elimination and Feature Importance from Tree-based Models.

After that, you can use a TPE optimizer like Optuna to efficiently explore the hyperparameter space for your models. Then you can build an ensemble such as a voting classifier using Ridge regressor coefficients or `scipy.minimize` to find the optimal weights.

Remember, always trust your cross validation scores! Good luck.